# How to access inner directives of the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've directives `container` and `item`.

```js
directive('container', function(){
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: "<div>contains <p>...</p> </div>'
    }
});


directive('item', function(){
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: "item"
    }
});
```

They are supposed to be used like this:

```html
<container>
    <item>
    <item>
    <item>
</container>
```

Expected output html:

```html
<div>contains <p>item item item </p> </div>
```

How to take `item` directives from `container` content and render them as repeatable directive in place of `...` at container template?

Comment: Just google "AngularJS directive transclusion"

Comment: @Blackhole I see that transclusion is a right way to solve it, but can't find good example.

Comment: The best one is, as often, [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since directive templates must have exactly one html root element, `template: "item"` is not valid. It has to be at least something like `template: '<span>item</span>'`, which produces:

```
<div>
    contains 
    <p>
        <span>item</span>
        <span>item</span>
        <span>item</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

The two directives are:

```
app.directive('container', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div>contains <p ng-transclude></p></div>'
  };
});

app.directive('item', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<span>item</span>'
  };
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E2PTwKbePc8vivIbuAtZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `transclude: true` option :

```
directive('container', function(){
    return {
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div>contains <p ng-transculde></p> </div>'
    }
});
```